# How can I theme Media fields?

Tags: theming, media

I use Media + File Entity projects.
I have content type with field_media_picture (widget: Media file selector) which then connected with Media image file.
The Media Image file type has field_picname (text).
I've Managed display for the Media Image file type to display: image file and field_picname.
I've created field--field_media_picture.tpl.php:

```
<?php print render($items);?>
```

This code show image + field_picname. It's OK.

But how can I get these fields (image and field_picname) separately in PHP?
I want to theme these fields individually.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've themed these fields through code:

```
<?php
hide($items[0]['field_picname']);
print render($items);
print render($items[0]['field_picname']);
?>
```

But I'm not sure the code is the best.